# Как сделать запуск функции при первом клике по ссылке?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть функция которую нужно запустить по клику, "console.log()".

Токлько нюанс в том, чтоб функция запускалась при первом клике, при следующих кликах на протяжении 2-х секунд фунция не должна запускаться, а уже по истечению 2-х секунд при клике функция опять запускалась.

Comment: флаг и таймаут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение в лоб: проверять при клике флаг, если выставлен - выходить, если ент запускать тайм аут

Например:

```
var allowclick = true;
function onclick(){
    if(!allowClick) return;
    allowClick = false;
    //do function
    console.log(...)
    setTimeout(function(){allowClick = true; },2000)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

html

```
<input type="button" id="test" value="123213">
```

javascript

```
var timeout;
var clearInterval = true;

$(document).on('click', '#test', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (clearInterval) {
        clearInterval = false;
        console.log('test phrase');

        timeout = setTimeout(function() { 
            clearTimeout(timeout); 
            clearInterval = true;
        }, 2000);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Upd:

Как говорят в комментарии: *кстати, нет смысла делать clearTimeout внутри обработчика, это ж не интервал, он и сам очистится, одноразовый ведь. Был бы смысл очищать - снаружи, чтобы прервать таймер*

Я оставил на всякий случай, но можете поиграться, чтоб понять нужен он или нет.

Comment: что-то ты как-то накрутил. мне кажется:)

Comment: .....¯\\_(ツ)_/¯.....очищать интервал надо же... плюс флаг обнулять...

Comment: кстати, нет смысла делать `clearTimeout` внутри обработчика, это ж не интервал, он и сам очистится, одноразовый ведь. Был бы смысл очищать - снаружи, чтобы прервать таймер

Answer (score 2):

Ну и я

```js
$(function() {
  var flag = true;
  $('a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (flag) {
      console.log('flag=' + flag);
      $('#res').text($('#res').text() + ' flag=' + flag)
      flag = false;
      setTimeout(function() {
        flag = true;
      }, 2000);
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Link</a>
<div id="res"></div>
```